# Why does rigidity hold only if rank >1?

Tags: number-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

In simple words, why does Margulis' superrigidity and arithemiticit only hold for lattices in Lie groups of rank $>1$? E.g. what is the reason for it to fail for $SL(2,R)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to exhibit counterexamples for $SL(2,\mathbb R)$.  E.g. there are non-constant families of curves of genus $>1$, such as
$$y^2 = x(x-1)(x-2)(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$$
(just to write down an example for genus two).

By the uniformization theorem, these give rise to a non-constant family
of conjugacy classes of cocompact lattices in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$.
In particular, since there are only countably many conjugacy classes
of arithmetic groups in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$, most of these (uncountably many)
conjugacy classes must consist of non-arithmetic lattices.

One way to summarize this answer is to say that *curves are not rigid*. 
Since curves are not rigid, and they correspond to conjugacy classes of
cocompact lattices in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ by uniformization, it must be that
cocompact lattices in $Sl(2,\mathbb R)$ are not rigid either.

---

By considering punctured curves, we can similarly show that finite covolume
lattices in $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ need not be rigid either.